# How to install python 2.6.8 on windows 7?

Tags: python, windows-7

I have downloaded the two releases of python 2.6.8 from here http://www.python.org/getit/releases/2.6.8/ and I don't know how to install that on my Windows 7 64bit OS. Please someone help me. I searched but I can't find good tutorial.

Thanks!

Comment: So is the issue the fact it's a tar file??

Comment: The security fix only releases need to be compiled; you may want to read http://docs.python.org/devguide/setup.html#windows-compiling (or you may just want to install the binary of the latest 2.7 release)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2.6.8 is a source only release. Download either 2.6.6 or 2.7.3 depending on your requirements, which come with Windows installers.

Comment: Here is the link for python with windows installer https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.6.5/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to install Python 2.6.8 on a Windows machine, you can do the following:

If you don't have Microsoft Visual Studio, install it: the Express edition is available here: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products

Unzip your source code to a folder (lets call it E:\Python) and open E:\Python\PCbuild\pcbuild.sln in Visual Studio.

Set your build configuration to Debug for Win32 (available under Build => Configuration Manager.

Build your solution. You should see errors, these are related to modules for which patches were released such as zlib and sqlite. Fixing those is a little outside my expertise regarding a Python Windows install but there are patches available as I've resolved some of them on my Unix builds.

In any case, there should now be a python_d.exe file in your E:\Python\PCbuild folder. This is your Python executable.

Comment: Haha, too much effort. I will stick to 2.6.6 ^^. Thanks tho

Comment: Oh it's a pain in the hole alright, I agree, but sometimes it's necessary - for example until recently Amazon Elastic Beanstalk only shipped with Python 2.6.8 so if you were designing software for those kind of stacks, and you wanted parity of code compatability, you'd need a development machine running Python 2.6.8